# Sharepoint Designer - Creating a simple Workflow, check status of another Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a simple workflow using the Sharepoint Designer. We already have one user-defined workflow, called *Internal Approval*. This creates a column with the same name.
Basically, my workflow should perform:
Conditions:

```
if Internal Approval equals Approved 
   and Status equals Draft //custom field I want to set, this works
```

The problem, after a quick debug, is that the *Internal Approval* does not equal to `Approved` nor contains it, *Internal Approval* equals **16**.
The question: what is this number, and can I rely on it always being 16 for an approved workflow?
Or better, how can I check a if another workflow was approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this could help you [Workflow Status](http://kmukesh.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/workflow-status/)

Reference [Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowstatus.aspx) from MSDN, just type case the above Enum to Integer you will get the values.

Also to filter based on the Workflow Status  in the View. [Refer](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2006/12/11/howto-filter-a-view-based-on-workflow-status.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I tried to find a verified source for that (MS), but couldn't. I should also add these codes work for filtering of views, not just from the designer, so I should have known this by now... Thanks again.

Comment: Here you go Reference Article from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowstatus.aspx  for the status (Cast the above enum value to Integer you will get those values) and to Filter based on the View http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2006/12/11/howto-filter-a-view-based-on-workflow-status.aspx